# Sliding transition for list items when one is removed

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

It has been a while since I last used CSS. I'm having trouble with this one. I have a list of items. When I click on the cross it removes the item from the DOM. However what I'm looking for is to **make the rest of the items slide up** when one has been removed.

Currently it just removes the item as desired but instantly moves the other to 'fill in the space'. I know there is a way to do it with CSS transitions, but the question is how...

```js
var remove = function(id) {
  document.querySelector('#'+id).remove();
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px
}
span {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">One <span onclick="remove('one')">×</span></div>
<div id="two">Two <span onclick="remove('two')">×</span></div>
<div id="three">Three <span onclick="remove('three')">×</span></div>
<div id="four">Four <span onclick="remove('four')">×</span></div>
```

Comment: I think you must use animations instead of transitions

Answer (score 10):

Like this?

I added a class called `closeSlide` which will animate the element to slide up. And after the transition, it is removed by setting up a timer.

And for visual prettiness, I've added `overflow:hidden` to your target style, which can alternatively, be added via JS using `elem.style.overflow = 'hidden'`. But for justification, I added that to the target style because I want to avoid any possible jitters when initiating the closing animation.

```js
var remove = function(id) {
  var elem = document.querySelector('#'+id);
  elem.className += 'closeSlide';
  setTimeout(function(){
    elem.remove();
  }, 200);
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
span {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.closeSlide {
  margin-bottom:0;
  height:0px;
  padding-top:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
  transition: 0.2s all ease-out;
  /*Just reverse any spacing styling you've applied to make it **magically** disappear*/
}
```

```html
<div id="one">One <span onclick="remove('one')">×</span></div>
<div id="two">Two <span onclick="remove('two')">×</span></div>
<div id="three">Three <span onclick="remove('three')">×</span></div>
<div id="four">Four <span onclick="remove('four')">×</span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it looks good but is there a way to do this only with a css property applied to all items (like transition : linear ?).

Comment: @Ivan, I don't quite get what you mean :/ If you remove the other properties, the animation will not look as smooth, you can try and fiddle with the properties to see for yourself.